# Removing named callbacks that are wrapped in an anonymous functions?

Tags: node.js, callback, listeners

**Is there a way to remove the listeners on a passed in named callback function that are wrapped in an anonymous function?**

UPDATE. More complete code examples below.

Here are the details.
I've a function that gets passed in a named callback.

**Before**

```
function read (message, named_callback ) {

    var named_callback  = named_callback || default_callback
       , message        = message || "Choose: ";

    stdout.write(message);
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', named_callback);
    });
};
```

All the `named_callback`s take and prepare a passed in user input (answer).

```
answer =  answer.trim().toLowerCase();
```

I end up repeating the trimming and lowercasing line everywhere! I wanted to move this step into one place, so tried to prepare the answer before it got passed into the callback.
I wrote this:

**After**

```
function read (message, named_callback ) {

    var named_callback  = named_callback || default_callback
       , message        = message || "Choose: ";

    stdout.write(message);
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', function (answer) {
        answer =  answer.trim().toLowerCase();
        named_callback(answer);
    });
};
```

However, this results in event listeners not being removed, and they just pile up until the program crashes with too many listeners.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is probably not where you think it is. with the info you give i would expect you just call the read method everytime, and thats where the tomanylisteners comes into place, because you just everytime append a new 'data' listener. if you change that 'on' to 'once' your application shouldnt crash anymore:

```
stdin.once('data'...
```

this of course isnt the solution to your problem, it is just to illustrate where your problem is (its not the trim/tolowercase.

if you show as a little bit more of your code maybe we are able to help you better, but probably your read-method is just unecessary overhead...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated the code so it's more complete, because, yeh, as I had it, it looked like the wrapping function added no value. I think `once` might solve issue. Going to rewrite code with it. I'll circle back. In the mean time, you know if other way to track listeners and remove them?

Comment: @hearandnow78 The `once` method solved my issue. Thank you for suggesting it.